# How to add dynamic CRUD fields to application without publishing the new code?

Tags: asp.net

I'm using Asp.NET Web form Scaffolding  & MS SQL Server.

I would like to add the fields dynamically to UI when customer on demand.

**Ex:** Assume if we have asp.net page with fields like **Name** and **Address** field in the UI and user demands to add new fields like **phone** and **country** to the UI.

In above example, I don't want to write code again and  adding the fields in the UI then build it and then publish it.

Is there any option or mechanism in asp.net to do above thing without re-publishing the code?

Comment: Try to dynamically create elements like [This](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp)

Comment: Not as a HTML DOM. I'm looking for the solution from the DB to UI and UI to DB. In sense, If add a new field in the DB, it should get reflect in the UI and from the UI values should go back to the DB field.